# How to create a dynamic list of class objects?

Tags: python, list, class, object

When trying to add new element to my `cells` class object list, I noted that all list values are the last value of added item. I use append to add new items. How can I get the correct answer?

```
class cells:
  x=0
```

---

```
from cells import cells
a=[]

a.append(hucre)
a[0].x=10

a.append(hucre)
a[1].x=20

a.append(hucre)
a[2].x=30

print(a[0].x) #30 where must give me 10
print(a[1].x) #30 where must give me 20
print(a[2].x) #30 where must give me 10
```

Comment: What is `hucre`?

Comment: ``"i use append to add new items"`` no, you are adding the same object over and over, no wonder that if you change it once, all instances change. And please specify what ``hucre`` is, or even better, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Plus it looks as if ``x`` is a class variable, not an instance variable, you should look up the difference.

Comment: You can use the `type(cls_name, bases, namespace)` to create classes dynamically. Where name, bases, namespace are string, tuple, dict respectively.

Comment: "hucre" is same class name "cells", i wrong writes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your class you defined x within the class's body, not it's `__init__` method. That makes it a class variable, one and the same for all instances of the class, as per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 0):

You should create new instaces of class `cells`, not changing `cells`'s class `cells.x` attribute.

So you should define `__init__` method for class `cells` (more info about `__init__`: [link](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InitializationAndCleanup.html), [link](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)):

```
class cells:
    def __init__(self, x=None):  # default value of x is None
        self.x = x


hucre = cells()  # instantiating new cells object
print(hucre.x)

Out: 
None
```

Appending values to the list:

```
a = []   
a.append(hucre)
a[0].x = 10
print(a[0].x)

Out: 
10
```

Create new object, otherwise you'll change first object:

```
hucre = cells(20)
a.append(hucre) # here .x is 20 already so you need no assignment 
print(a[1].x)

Out: 
20
```

...and so on. You could append objects instantiated inside parens:

```
a.append(cells(30))
print(a[2].x)

Out: 
30
```